# Slim3 optional parameter with controller method as callback

Tags: slim, slim-3, custom-routes

I have route:

```
$app->get('/admin/login/{status}', 'App\Controller\Admin\AdminController:loginAction')
```

How do I make {status} parameter optional?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use square brackets:

```php
$app->get('/admin/login[/{status}]', 'App\Controller\Admin\AdminController:loginAction')
```

See http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders

Comment: Thank you. I find it hard to understand why is every aspect of slim3 documentation about function() callback.

Comment: This is because no one has contributed any other documentation. We welcome pull requests to https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Website.